# modify the name of the :id to :another_id in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Well I googled my question but I couldn't find anything or I it's not the correct question..

The issue is I need modify the primary_key name of the database :id with :another_id, in my project I need to use pgrouting and it contains several plsql functions and these functions uses the primary-key with the name gid and instead of modify the plsql functions is better change the id name, and  I was thinking do this with a migration becouse I thought it's the rails way.

Is it possible, and how I can do this ??

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

**Edit**

```
  create_table :pruebas, primary_key: :gid do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.timestamps
  end
```

This do the trick, and with this active record generate and uses the pk as gid.

Sorry if my question was not clear.. Gracias por las respuestas.

Comment: Are you asking to change the primary_key of a table to a different column other than id? Or do you want the URL to be something like /items/super-item-name rather than /items/5

Comment: I want to change the primary_key name in the db from id to another_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the primary key yourself, when you create the table, you would do:

```
create_table(:table_name, primary_key: 'gid') do |t|
   ...
end
```

And you need to define the primary key name in your model:

```
self.primary_key = 'gid'
```

Comment: Well the database doesn't exist, and the plsql function I need use infers the pk as gid and if I modify  this I should rewrite a lot of functions, thats why I want to set the pk as gid directly from the migration, then I can use active-record functions to manipulate the data from db. Is it valid?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience using PostgreSQL or pgRouting, but I believe what you're looking for is a method for instructing ActiveRecord to use a different column as the primary key.

I believe you're looking for set_primary_key.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key "gid"
end
```